# sum of intger inputs javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, calculator

i have this function to calculate the sum of 3 inputs :

```js
function calculateTotal() {

 var result = fd.field('_x002D_ESO').value() + fd.field('Artdesk').value() + fd.field('OtherDesign').value();

    // put the result somewhere into your form
 
 document.getElementsByClassName("myOutput")[0].innerHTML = "Le budget total est : " + result;

}

 

fd.field('_x002D_ESO').change(calculateTotal);

fd.field('Artdesk').change(calculateTotal);

fd.field('OtherDesign').change(calculateTotal);

calculateTotal();
        });
```

example . if i put 1 in the first field and 2 in the second and 3 in the third field ,  i dont get the sum, what i get is 123
any solution?

Comment: Can you run this piece on JSFiddle?

Comment: I just created a basic fiddle of what you may want using jquery and javascript: https://jsfiddle.net/chengsieuly/rzrhgxzs/1 Something like this should work. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fd.field('_x002D_ESO').value() is returning a string, you need to cast it to an integer. If the string is empty or otherwise falsy, we then set the value to be 0.

```
var value1 = parseInt(fd.field('_x002D_ESO').value()) || 0;
var value2 = parseInt(fd.field('Artdesk').value()) || 0;
var value3 = parseInt(fd.field('OtherDesign').value()) || 0;

var result = value1 + value2 + value3;
```

Comment: i try it and still doesn t work, i get the same result

Comment: can you console.log them? What's the error? There might be some whitespace causing parseInt to fail

Comment: this is what i put :
function calculateTotal() {

    var result = parseInt(fd.field('_x002D_ESO').value()) + parseInt(fd.field('Artdesk').value()) + parseInt(fd.field('OtherDesign').value());
    // put the result somewhere into your form
 
 document.getElementsByClassName("myOutput")[0].innerHTML = "Le budget total est : " + result;

}

 

fd.field('_x002D_ESO').change(calculateTotal);

fd.field('Artdesk').change(calculateTotal);

fd.field('OtherDesign').change(calculateTotal);

calculateTotal();
        });

Comment: i dont have console error but i get the same result : if i put 1 in te frst field and 2 in the second i get 12

Comment: that's very strange, could you put a console.log(result) after the var result line?

Comment: thanks it work just fine , i have only one issue by default : is NAN how can i change this message error ?

Comment: yeah NaN (not a number) is a problem because when you use parseInt on an empty string, you will get NaN. The solution to this is to detect when you get NaN and replace it with 0. Solution updated